# Chrome extension popup resizability by user

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup

I'm currently designing a Chrome Extension
and I want to make **the size of the popup itself changeable by user.**

`popup.html` is the content that goes inside the popup.
So in order to do something with the popup itself,
I think I'll have to work with the codes in `popup.js`,
but before starting, I want to know **if this is possible.**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by popup?. Is that a functionality?. or you mean the underlying popup which gets displayed when you click some extensions?

Comment: @DavidR As you can see in this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) popup refers to to the latter, the most generic one in which the html codes are rendered. Google named the default files "popup" so it might be confusing. Thxx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borders of the extension toolbar popup aren't resizable, but you can implement the functionality yourself by adding 3 thin div elements (4px x 100%, for example) on sides of the popup except for the top, add `mousedown` event listener on each one that will set a global boolean flag, which will be used in `mousemove` handler, and unset in `mouseup`. To actually resize the popup simply set `document.body.style.width = newWidth + 'px'`, for example. To provide visual cues add `:hover` CSS on those `div` elements with corresponding `cursor: ....` rule.

Answer (score 2):

Besides @wOxxOm's answer, you could also add a div inside popup body and set its [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/resize) CSS property `both`.

style:

```
div {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div>
    I am div
  </div>
</body>
```

[image]